# Get value of a key which starts with a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I ran into a problem using the Pipedrive API. I tried to get some data using the below but it returned an error:

```
$.each(data.data, function(key,value) {
    console.log(value.0d1df598a5539ab5b6b410b339dc9218e0acb091);
});
```

However this works:

```
$.each(data.data, function(key,value) {
    console.log(value.person_name);
});
```

Why can't I get values of the keys that are complex strings generated by the Pipedrive system?

Comment: why do you call this "complex"? you simply did not know how to do  `obj[name]`, I think that is an extremely basic thing to know about a language before getting stuck and asking here.  Nothing here is **complex**, it merely starts with a number, which is forbidden to use the way you've used i,t using a dot notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve what you require you would need to use bracket notation as the first character of the property identifier is an integer. Try this:

```js
var value = {
    '0d1df598a5539ab5b6b410b339dc9218e0acb091': 'foo bar'
}

console.log(value['0d1df598a5539ab5b6b410b339dc9218e0acb091']);
```

Comment: Thank's! It worked just right. Can you explain why dows it work like that? Why can I get not that complex key names without a problem?

Comment: It's not that the name is too complex - it's simply that it begins with an integer and when using that format (`xxx.xxx`) JS thinks that you're trying to define a floating point value, not retrieve a value from an object.

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation can be summarized in two part

1. Valid javascript variable(identifier names)
   An identifier must start with `$`, `_`, or any character in the Unicode categories `Uppercase letter (Lu)`, `Lowercase letter`, `Titlecase letter (Lt)`, `Modifier letter (Lm)`, `Other letter (Lo)`, or `Letter number (Nl)`.

   In your case the identifier name start with an integer(0)
2. Property accessors

   An key of an object in js can be retrieved either by using `dot` (`.`) notation or by using `Bracket`[]` notation

Square brackets notation allows use of characters that cannot be used with dot notation and also to retrieve an identifier which is not valid according to the first point.Beside it also allows to access properties containing special characters.

This is because js interpreter automatically converts the expression within square brackets to a string & retrieves the corresponding value.Actually 
js evaluates the first complete expression with square brackets in a statement, runs `toString()` on it to convert it into a string and then uses that value for the next bracket expression, on down the line till it runs out of bracket expressions.

So `dot notation` has marginal upper-hand since it wont go throught he above process.

But **it cannot be use it with a variable(or number)**.

It only allow to access explicit key name of a property

Since the identifier in your object identifiers's name starts with an 0 , bracket notation like `value['0d1df598a5539ab5b6b410b339dc9218e0acb091']` will give it's value.